# I can't run apache (ubuntu server)

Tags: apache2, webserver

I can't run apache (ubuntu server)

This is my output in terminal:

```
root@srv etc/init.d/apache2 start
 * Starting web server apache2                                                                                       
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
domain name, using 2a01:4f8:191:61af::2 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some other program which is running at port 80.

You need to edit `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file as follows

replace the line which says

`Listen 80`

to

`Listen 33333`

Your apache will be listening for incoming connections at port 33333 now. You can give any port number instead of 33333. Make sure that the port number which you choose is between 1025 and 65535. The ports below 1024 are used by commonly available applications.

Comment: Thanks. `httpd.conf` was empty default. Now is: `Listen 33333` and in `etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite` I have `<VirtualHost *:33333>` but still not working. (nginx is running at port 80)

Comment: Its actually ports.conf. I updated my answer. Please check that.

Comment: Thanks. Problem with ports solved. Do you have any hint for `apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified
domain name, using 2a01:4f8:191:61af::2 for ServerName`?

Comment: Can you please try this http://aslamnajeebdeen.com/blog/how-to-fix-apache-could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-using-127011-for-servername-error-on-ubuntu?

Comment: You can set the server name in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` make this the 1st line `ServerName my-epic-server-name-here` Oh and by the way you can start apache2 using `service apache2 start`